# Defining a function by right limits

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $D$ be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and continuous. Define $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$$g(x):= \inf\{f(t) : t \in D, t> x\}. $$

Then $g$ is necessarily right-continuous and increasing. But, apparently, it need not be left-continuous. (My question is to find such an example). However, I cannot find an example of this. An $f$ giving rise to a non-continuous $g$ must not be uniformly continuous. But since $f$ is bounded and continuous on any interval finite interval $[a,b]$ is it not necessarily uniformly continuous there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f$ is only continuous on "$D$-intervals" $[a,b] \cap D$, which in general are not compact, hence $f$ will not be automatically uniformly continuous there. For example, define $f \colon \mathbf Q \to \mathbf R$ by 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x < \sqrt 2 \\ x + 1 & x > \sqrt 2 
\end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is increasing and continuous, but 
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} x & x < \sqrt 2 \\ x +1 & x \ge \sqrt 2 
\end{cases} $$
is not continuous at $\sqrt 2$.